# How to programatically remove a value transformer from a Binding in NSBindingOption

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I'm binding NSValueTransformer programatically to NSTextField property on demand in a macOS application. My question is how can I remove this binding?

Relevant code snippet to bind the NSValueTransformer:

```
@IBOutlet var plcAddrLabel: NSTextField!

@objc dynamic var registerAddr = Int(1)

var optionsDict: [NSBindingOption : Any] = [:]

optionsDict = [NSBindingOption.valueTransformer:decToHexTransformer(), NSBindingOption.valueTransformerName:NSValueTransformerName.decToHexTransformerName]
            
plcAddrLabel.bind(.value, to: self, withKeyPath: "plcRegisterAddress" , options: optionsDict)
```

When it comes to unbinding I have tried a number of different approaches:

The following code

```
optionsDict = [NSBindingOption.valueTransformer: "<null>", NSBindingOption.valueTransformerName: "<null>"]
plcAddrLabel.bind(.value, to: self, withKeyPath: "plcRegisterAddress" , options: optionsDict)
```

causes this error upon execution:

> -[NSTaggedPointerString transformedValue:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b73031cc07cbe65

The reason for using `"<null>"` is that it is returned by **plcAddrLabel.infoForBinding(.value)** before binding the NSValueTransformer for the first time:

`NSValueTransformer = "<null>";`

`NSValueTransformerName = "<null>";`

I have also tried

```
optionsDict = [NSBindingOption.valueTransformer: NSBindingOption.nullPlaceholder, NSBindingOption.valueTransformerName: NSBindingOption.nullPlaceholder]
```

unfortunately the result is the same.

Interestingly **plcAddrLabel.infoForBinding(.value)** also shows:

`NSNullPlaceholder = "<null>";`

It appears, as soon as I try to remove/clear the transformer option the transformer gets called.

**Note:** while the transformer is bound to the NSTextfield it works fine. Replacing one transformer with another transformer also works.

Any suggestions for further diagnosis would be much appreciated.

Xcode 13.2.1

Comment: Just an idea: use a formatter instead of a value transformer?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you wanted this

```
plcAddrLabel.unbind(.value)
```

Comment: Now I think that the reason is not in the provided code. Needed minimal reproducible example or access to project.

Comment: Thanks Asperi, you are correct, **unbind** will clear the transformer, followed by a **bind**  operation with nil options does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking or [`NSObject.unbind(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1458088-unbind)

> It appears, as soon as I try to remove/clear the transformer option the transformer gets called. Note: while the transformer is bound to the NSTextfield it works fine.

Could you elaborate on this?

> The following code
>
> ```
> optionsDict = [NSBindingOption.valueTransformer: "<null>", NSBindingOption.valueTransformerName: "<null>"]
> plcAddrLabel.bind(.value, to: self, withKeyPath: "plcRegisterAddress" , options: optionsDict)
> ```
>
> causes this error upon execution:

Of course it does! `"<null>"` is just a string, with absolutely no special semantic value in this context. It's not an `NSValueTransformer`, and doesn't respond to the `transformedValue` message.

---

Side note, this code doesn't make much sense:

```
var optionsDict: [NSBindingOption : Any] = [:]

optionsDict = [NSBindingOption.valueTransformer:decToHexTransformer(), NSBindingOption.valueTransformerName:NSValueTransformerName.decToHexTransformerName]
            
plcAddrLabel.bind(.value, to: self, withKeyPath: "plcRegisterAddress" , options: optionsDict)
```

You're making an empty dictionary to assign to `optionsDict`, but you're then immediately replacing it with a new dictionary. This causes it to be needless mutable. It could just be:

```
let optionsDict: [NSBindingOption : Any] = [
    NSBindingOption.valueTransformer: decToHexTransformer(),
    NSBindingOption.valueTransformerName: NSValueTransformerName.decToHexTransformerName
]

plcAddrLabel.bind(.value, to: self, withKeyPath: "plcRegisterAddress" , options: optionsDict)
```

Better yet, if you inlined it, the type and used some implicit member expressions, it gets even nicer:

```
plcAddrLabel.bind(.value, to: self, withKeyPath: "plcRegisterAddress" , options: [
    .valueTransformer: decToHexTransformer(),
    .valueTransformerName: NSValueTransformerName.decToHexTransformerName
])
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander, sorry, the reason for the empty dictionary is not apparent from the code sample I have provided. In the full code I create an empty dictionary, then add the transformer conditionally before passing the dictionary into **bind**.